# How to keep stack frame right in ARM with GNU -Os?

Tags: linux, gcc, arm

I am building and running an application with arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc, and I am testing a stack backtrace function in Linux.
Then I found if the application is built with -Os option, the stack backtrace does NOT work as expected. Without -Os, it can show the backtrace well.

I want to keep the compiled code as small as possible, but still need the stack backtrace to work as expected.  So which GCC option(s) should I use to achieve this?

I referred to GCC optimization options at [GCC optimization options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options)  , as it says the -Os includes options of -O1 and -O2 (excludes 7 options).  I worked out a BASH script to add those options one by one to GCC compiling, and check backtrace results, but I did NOT find which option causes the error, did I miss something in -Os of GCC?

Comment: Possibly `-fno-omit-frame-pointer`?

Comment: I don't think it is that option to cause the difference. I did testing with/without -fomit-frame-pointer, the generated stack backtrace worked as expected.  And I am thinking -Os does something else than -O1 + -O2, but GCC does not list it and my testing has not find it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the cause of problem.
With GCC -O1, the backtrace does NOT work as expected, and by adding `-fno-inline` the problem can be fixed.
With GCC -Os, adding `-fno-inline` can NOT work well. Instead, `-fkeep-static-functions` can help backtrace working well in this case.

So `-fkeep-static-functions` is the key option in this case to both make backtrace work and keep execution size as small as possible.